# How to limit authentication/sign-up request to custom email domains with Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, gmail

Is there a way to limit use of a web app to only users who have access to a specific custom Gmail domain. e.g users must have a '@companyName.ac.uk'email address in order to successfully sign-up/create an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just Firebase Authentication, no, you can’t limit who authenticates-it just *authenticates* users. Controlling what kind of privileges various users are granted is an issue of *authorization* and that’s up to the developer to build. That being said, Firebase does offer some features that can help like auth token custom claims, server-side Functions, and Firestore/Real-time Database access rules. Which combination of these works best for you depends on how you’re building you app.